# How to make my own command with parameters

Tags: command-line, java

I am tired of

```
 javac filename.java
```

and then

```
 java filename
```

isn't there a way to make my own command?

```
mycommand filename.java
```

And the `filename.java` is both compiled and run??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create really small bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
javac "$1"
java `basename "$1" .java`
```

Put this to `/usr/local/bin/runjava.sh`, and execute

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/runjava.sh
```

Then you can just type

```
runjava.sh filename.java
```

to compile and run it.

Alternatively, you can put `runjava.sh` (or your own name to it) to `~/bin` folder. If that folder do not exist, you can create it with command `mkdir ~/bin`. After opening new terminal, it's in your `PATH` automatically (assuming Ubuntu and bash, without `.bashrc` customizations).

First method adds it to all users in your system, second one only to you.

Comment: I'd suggest putting the sh file in ~/bin directory, so it is easy to access and will be available for this user only. (Not that your location is any wrong, just saying)

Comment: @Shrikant Also, adding `~/bin` to `PATH` may be good idea when doing it that way.

Comment: I think it is added to `PATH` by default, if the directory exists... am not on ubuntu right now, so, can't check.

Comment: @Shrikant: ah, true, you are right. It's automatically added in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

So, assuming bash (You are running ubuntu right? ;) ), you can create a function for this...

```
j () {
  javac "$1" && java "${1%.*}"
}
```

and then if you have a file called `PureJavaAwesomeness.java`, you could do

```
j PureJavaAwesomeness.java
```

and that should compile and run the java file.

Edit: And, you might want to put that function definition at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file, so it is loaded every time you open your terminal.

Edit2: For some more awesomeness, you can use this function

```
j () {
  cname=${1//\//.}
  cname=${cname%.*}
  javac "$1" && java "$cname"
}
```

This will work even when you do `j com/ssk/apps/PackagedClass.java`, assuming the package of the `PackagedClass.java` is `com.ssk.apps`. (Not tested, but should work).

Comment: why downvote this answer?

Comment: Tested your latter function, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

**THIS IS AN OVERKILL FOR WHAT YOU NEED BUT SOMEONE ELSE MIGHT STUMBLE UPON THE QUESTION SEARCHING FOR "HOW TO MAKE OWN COMMANDS ON UBUNTU".**

You can use quickly ubuntu-cli-application template to create commands and easily package them as debs or share using ppas.

You'll need some knowledge of python though.

First install **Quickly** from the Software Center.

Then in the terminal type,

```
quickly create ubuntu-cli my-program-name
```

This will create a project directory for you complete with command line handling structure. All you have to do is to edit the files to add your own commands.

Once done, you can share your new commands with friends using

```
quickly package
```

This will create a DEB package ready to be installed on any Ubuntu machine.